# Undo git commit with TortoiseGit

Tags: git, commit, tortoisegit

I'm using TortoiseGit in Windows for my git projects.

I made a local commit on my project. And I want to undo it.

How to undo git commit with TortoiseGit? without discarding my changes

Comment: Would you mind to use the command-line `git` client for this operation?

Comment: @user3159253 I know how to undo with command-line. I want to undo with Tortoise. I do not want to play with 2 tools

Comment: Ah, Ok :) Personally I think that most if not all VCS GUIs suck but certainly your exprerience may differ.

Comment: What do you mean by "without discarding my changes"? The local changes? The commits you want to keep except the one you want to undo?

Comment: How do you undo with command line?

Answer (score 16):

## Abstract

If you don't want to discard the working tree changes, using **Reset with Mixed** option **or commit** it with another branch to keep it.

If you want to keep **changes in a commit**, do what you want to do except clean up the repository(garbage collection). **Those changes can be retrieved later.**

---

## Detail Steps

2023/12

```
Win10  
TortoiseGit 2.15.1.0  
git version 2.43.0.windows.1
```

### Undo last commit: `Reset` with `Mixed` option

Condition:

- Working Tree has some changes and you want to keep it.
- Or, Working Tree is clean, but you want to keep local changes as same as last commit.

[image]

and

[image]

The result:
[image]

If pushing `F5` to refresh, that last commit will be invisible.
[image]
***I will show you how to retrieve that commit later.***

### Undo last commit: `Reset` with `Hard` option

If you don't care the Working Tree Changes nor the last commit's changes, perform Git Reset with **Hard**.

[image]

The result:
[image]

Also, that last commit will be invisible after pushing `F5`.
But, it can be retrieved.

### Retrieve invisible commit

You could create a local branch `keep` to keep the commit at the beginning. Like this:
[image]

**If not...**
Since you have done the commit, that commit will exist in the near future. So you can find it back by using Reflog.

[image]

Then, you can show log for that invisible commit, or create a local branch for it.
[image]

**NOTE**: Those invisible commits will be accessible until the repository is cleaned up.

## Undo/Remove the commit which is not the last one: `Rebase with Force`

[image]

and

[image]

(You may hit the conflicts, but how to resolve the conflicts is another story. :P )

[image]

The Result:
[image]

**NOTE:** Also, you can create `keep` branch at beginning or by using Reflog to retrieve it later. If so, the Graph of Show Log will be:
[image]

Comment: but you will lose changes also

Comment: With Rebase function, not lose that commit "3". User said this: "But I want to remove it from the history also." Suppose user meant that he want to remove "2", and not lose "3".

Comment: he wants to remove from history, but keep local changes

Comment: No. He didn't say "Local" changes.

Comment: he said: "without discarding my changes"

Comment: That does not mean local. And I think he want to keep the changes which are the other commits.

Comment: but I think he meant local changes. Better to ask him for clarification

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153915/discussion-between-yue-lin-ho-and-alexan).

Comment: with option Mixed reset will keep local changes

Comment: yap. it is true. :)

Comment: Added a note for reset mixed option.

Answer (score 6):

```
TortoiseGit -> Show Log -> Revert change by this commit
```

This will generate a commit that revert the commit, so you won't "lose" your changes.

Comment: I tried this. this will keep the old commit in the history. But I want to remove it from the history also

Comment: If you use `Reset`, it will lose the commit, unless you go to `reflog` as soon as possible (before garbage collection).

Comment: This worked for me. I use Tortoise Git client for windows version 2.4.0. The only change here is that there was no "Show Log" under TortoiseGit. There is one by the name "Show Reflog", which in turn showed all the commits. I could undo and create a new "undo commit". I am fine with the history being maintained.